# Remove app part title using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online

i want to remove the app part title (chrome title). I know i can do manually by going to edit properties and set chrome title to None. but i want that when i add the app part it automatically not display the app part title . i found one link using javascript which is as follows

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/hh185010(v=office.14).aspx

but iam using REST API anybody done with REST API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [article](http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/remove-sharepoint-app-part/).

In this article there is readymade piece of code which you can use for the functionality of remove app part.

Comment: Can you please add the brief description from the link. In long run links may break.

Comment: This link might have been relevant at some point, but the domain is now just advertising.